# createObjectUrl does not exist

Tags: angular

I want use `URL.createObjectURL` in my project, but when I compile project I get:
error TS2339: Property 'createObjectURL' does not exist on type 'URL'.
WebStorm also doesn't see this method in URL I have to do something like `URL.prototype.createObjectURL` but anyway I still getting that error.

example how I would like to use it (or should work)

```
private createUrl(image: Blob) {
return URL.createObjectURL(image) }
```

Comment: Works fine for me in `es2015`

Comment: I use es2017 but in other project also has this es and work great

Comment: @Lukasz check if you imported something for `URL`. I use WebStorm and compiles fine, and not TSLINT error.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just had old version of Webstorm :D